# external boot drive doesn't boot from usb 3.0 but boots from usb 2.0

Tags: boot, usb-3

I have installed ubuntu 18.04 on external SSD (internal SSD has windows 10, which I removed when making this boot drive, so all the boot files are on external SSD).

I was able to boot it from USB 3.0 for a time, but recently my system has stopped recognizing this drive if I plug it into USB 3.0, but boots just fine if I plug it into USB 2.0 port.

There is no issue with USB 3.0, I can copy the files from my android phone using this port.

I have searched on Google but couldn't find any solution.

How to make the drive boot again from USB 3.0?

Comment: Have you tried plugging it into a different USB port?

Comment: Yes, I plugged into USB 2 port of the laptop, it has booted just fine.

Comment: Some PC's do not support booting from 3.0, these were early adopters of usb 3.0. I have an HP laptop that does this, you can only boot from usb 2.0.

Comment: The boot drive has successfully booted from USB 3.0 port of my laptop for months, it has suddenly stopped recognizing this drive(in boot options for USB 3.0, but recognizes successfully for USB 2.0) for some reason unknown to me.

Comment: Reinstall OS...